# Why does water forms upward meniscus in glass tube but mercury forms a downward meniscus in same?

Tags: experimental-physics, surface-tension

Why does water forms upward meniscus in glass tube but mercury forms a downward meniscus in same? I know that adhesive forces in water are greater than cohesive but i dont undestand why?

Comment: As with almost any physical phenomena you can boil the reason down to energy. In the case of the meniscus, equilibrium between the surface energies of the gas, solid and liquid. Surface energies, surface tensions, contact angles, all related. Just google those terms and you will learn.

Comment: Water "wets" the glass, mercury does not. Water in a Teflon coated tube would form a mercury-like meniscus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only a question of the adhesive forces within the fluid. The adhesive (or repulsive) forces between the fluid and glass are also important.

Answer (score 2):

The detailed answer to 'why' the behavior is different is unknown to me. But, a little more detail than just saying its due to cohesive and adhesive forces, is the 'contact angle' . This angle is a function of the liquid, solid and gaseous media interacting with each other. It is also responsible for the various shapes of drops we see. So, if you're interested, here's a link: [wiki article on contact angle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_angle)

Self reading will be faster than me explaining it to you, but feel free to ask further questions if you're stuck.